# onclick replaces all images with lower number in src (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, image, onclick, toggleclass

I have a thermometer built out of 10 images. I would like to change each section (image) of the thermometer onclick, e.g. if you click on the 3rd image (which equals 30 degrees), the images below it (thermo2 and thermo1) also change. This works with the following (admittedly cumbersome) code:

```
<img src="thermo01_off.png" id="thermo1" class="img-swap" alt="10°" width="157" height="33" />
<img src="thermo01_off.png" id="thermo2" class="img-swap" alt="20°" width="157" height="33" />
<img src="thermo03_off.png" id="thermo3" class="img-swap" alt="30°" width="157" height="33" />
... and so on

$(function(){
    $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
       if ($(this).attr("id") == "thermo1") {
           thermo1.src = thermo1.src.replace("_off","_on");
       } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "thermo2") {
           thermo1.src = thermo1.src.replace("_off","_on");
           thermo2.src = thermo2.src.replace("_off","_on");
       } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "thermo3") {
           thermo1.src = thermo1.src.replace("_off","_on");
           thermo2.src = thermo2.src.replace("_off","_on");
           thermo3.src = thermo3.src.replace("_off","_on");
       }
 });
```

**Problem 1**
Currently the images don't toggle back off. I know you can use "toggleClass", but I am not sure how to implement in the above code.

**Problem 2**
If I implement the above code for all 10 thermometer images, it will get pretty long. There must be a much more efficient way of writing the above. Any suggestions.

**Solution**
This code worked in the end, thanks also to Gregg.

```
$(function() {
  $("[id^=thermo]").click(function() {
    var notid, thisid, new_url, not_url = "";
    var $this = $(this);

    //Get the ID without the "thermo" part
    thisid = $this.attr('id').replace('thermo', '');

    //swap image that was clicked
    new_url = $this.attr('src').replace("_off", "_on");
    $(".img-swap" + thisid).attr("src", new_url);

    //replaces all images that were NOT clicked
    $("[id^=thermo]").not(this).attr('id', function(i, idx) {

        //get ids of those not clicked
        notid = idx.replace('thermo', '');

        //change src of images with lower ids than the clicked one
        if (notid < thisid) {
            not_url = $(".img-swap" + notid).attr('src').replace("_off", "_on");
            console.log(notid);
            $(".img-swap" + notid).attr("src", not_url);
        } else {
            not_url = $(".img-swap" + notid).attr('src').replace("_on", "_off");
            $(".img-swap" + notid).attr("src", not_url);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Ps. should have mentioned that I iterated the class for each image as well,  e.g. img-swap1, img-swap2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$(function(){
// add click event listener to all imgs with id starting with 'thermo'
$('img[id^="thermo"]').click(function(){
    // get the index of the clicked element in the array of all matching elements
    var idx = $(this).index();
    // edit the src of the elements with an index less than the clicked element
    $.each($('img[id^="thermo"]'), function(i, img){
        if($(img).index() <= idx){
            $(img).attr('src', $(img).attr('id') + '_on');
        }else{
            $(img).attr('src', $(img).attr('id') + '_off');
        }
    });
});
```

});

EDIT: As long as the id of the image is the same as the name of the image files like your sample html shows. this will work. I Changed it to a loop and using the IDs to set the image src.

Comment: Hi Gregg, thank you, I think that's nearly it. However, its not quite working yet, doesnt seem to be getting the index of  a clicked image and the src of the clicked image only changes if I change the line to 
this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on"); ... but cant seem to get the idx value ...

Comment: @Tina check the edited version. I know this will work as long as your actual html matches the sample you posted.

Comment: Thanks Gregg, thank you ever so much for your efforts. The updated function from you changed all images when I click on a particular image, no just the lower ones ... also it does not catch the correct src for the on image ... not to worry, I managed to get it working though, thanks to your input ... I have updated my question above. thanks again.

Comment: Actually gregg, your code could be working, except I would have to rename the images from thermo03_ to thermo3 ... the 0 is missing in the index number ... will have another go at getting your code working.